# How to convert non-well formed html to xhtml on iOS

Tags: html, ios, xpath, xhtml

Does anyone know how to convert non-well formed html to XHTML/XML on iOS?

I want to use xpath to parse an HTML page, but is not a well formed XML/XHTML.

Comment: I don't suppose you can do that manually? I mean, load the HTML into an HTML editor, export it as XHTML and then work with the result?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to convert it, or just use xpath?  https://github.com/topfunky/hpple or some other tools can parse non-well-formed html.